# Change XBee shield TX/RX Software serial?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, xbee

I am looking to have an Arduino UNO stack with a GSM Shield and an XBEE shield for wireless communication.

However, since the GSM Shield requires digital pins 2 and 3, I would have to reroute the RX/TX of the XBee to another digital pin.

I have tried changing

```
SoftwareSerial XBee(2, 3); // RX, TX
```

to other values, but this does not work.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you reroute the XBEE RX and TX lines to the new pins?

Comment: You won't be able to use the same pins for serial with the GSM shield and the Xbee. I would try moving the xbee shield so that its sits on a different series of pins. Make sure to be careful with the power and ground pine (ie don't hook them up to active IOs and do hook them up to the appropriate location)

Comment: @geometrikal Thanks for the advice, I forgotten to add jumper wires between the RX/TX to the new ports. That fixed it. Thanks for your help!